# Close Div overlay by clicking anywhere on the body

Tags: html, overlay, fade, jquery

This is what I've done:

```
$('#keks-overlay').hide();  

$('#click').click(function(){
    $('#keks-overlay').toggle(450);
});

$('#close-overlay').click(function(){
    $('#keks-overlay').toggle(250);
});
```

​
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rHKkD/22/

This works fine, but it shows/hides (toggles) only by clicking the "X" (#close-overlay).

I'd like do something like the fancybox-effect: fade out on clicking anywhere on the whole body.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event handler to a `div` that contains the whole page (or the document itself), and `hide()` the overlay in that handler.

```
$("#somebody").click(function() {
    $('#keks-overlay').hide(250);
});
```

However, if you want to prevent clicks on the overlay itself from triggering the `hide()`, you could either add an event handler to the overlay that returns false (to prevent the event from bubbling up), or place the overlay outside the `div` that holds the rest of your content (which works because the overlay has `absolute` positioning).

[I updated your fiddle to show the second method.](http://jsfiddle.net/rHKkD/25/)

Comment: WOW - awesome and simple man, thanks for sharing and updating the fiddle, pretty cool

Answer (score 1):

try (when document ready)

```
var inoverlay = false;
$('#keks-overlay').hover(function() {
    inoverlay = true;
}, function() {
    inoverlay = false;
});
```

then fetch all clicks on the document, check the inoverlay variable, if it's false hide your overlay, else do nothing. If you have a button that opens the overlay in the first place, be sure to check that it's not that button that's being clicked when you intercept clicks on the document.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if(inoverlay && (e.target.attr('id') != buttonForOverlay.attr('id') )) {
        closeOverlay();
    }
});
```